# MAMP on Windows - Click Start servers, nothing happens unless PHP 7.3.7 is in use

Tags: php, windows, mamp

MAMP version 4.1.1 for Windows
Running on Windows 8

If I have php 7.3.7 or php 7.3.0 selected then I start the servers and everything is fine.

If I try to use an earlier version of php, like php 7.0.0 or 5.6.37, then when I start the servers, nothing happens.  I mean, no lights flash, no message is given.  Nothing.  It just sits there as if nothing has been activated.  I will try to start the servers both by clicking the start servers button and by going to start servers under the Servers menu item.

I've looked in the error logs and nothing is jumping out at me.

Comment: If you are running Windows then you should be using WAMP.

Comment: WAMP has its own issues, and the client I'm working with wants to use MAMP.  Giving a response of, "Use different software," is seriously unhelpful.  MAMP has a Windows version so it is perfectly valid to use.

Comment: Have you looked at the server log files, the apps debug file, php log files? Have you contacted the vendors support group for assistance?

Comment: The app log files, to my reading, do not seem to indicate anything unusual.  I will take this up with MAMP support and post an answer when they respond.